# Using JavaScript Regex to match all html tags if attribute values may have ">" character

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want to match all html tags in a string with a RegEx `/<[^>]*>/g`

But some of tags have attributes with ">" in values, such as `<div :if="x > 1">`, can only get `<div :if="x>` as result.

How to modify the RegEx to fix this ?

---

Actually, I don't need to match all really valid html tags. I just need to match all `<***>`, with the '>' must not in quotes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 :)

Comment: Beware the coming of ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ

Comment: @Quentin is the attribute name `:if` valid markup. I can't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: `/<[^>"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^>"]*)*>/g`

Answer (score 1):

If you have the parsed HTML you can use css selectors with `document.querySelectorAll` to perform the operation of finding the elements for you.

`'[\\:if*=\\>]'` using the escape character `\\` you can directly search for the tagname `:if` and with the `*=` selector you can find the `>` (escaped) anywhere in the value for the attribute.

Im with @JonathanLowowski on this though. the attribute name `:if` looks incorrect and will probably fail in IE. But it does look like a namespaced attribute with no namespace.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[\\:if*=\\>]')

console.log(elements)
```

```html
<div :if="x > 1"></div>
<div :if="x"></div>
```